# Overlay image on a video using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I used this function to put an overlay image using OpenCV.

```
void OverlayImage(IplImage* src, IplImage* overlay, CvPoint location, CvScalar S, CvScalar D) {
for (int i = location.y; i < (location.y + overlay->height); i++) {
    for (int j = location.x; j < (location.x + overlay->width); j++) {
        CvScalar source = cvGet2D(src, i, j);
        CvScalar over   = cvGet2D(overlay, i-location.y, j-location.x);
        CvScalar merged;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            merged.val[i] = (S.val[i] * source.val[i] + D.val[i] * over.val[i]);

        cvSet2D(src, i + location.y, j + location.x, merged);
    }
}
}
```

and then used the function like this -

```
OverlayImage(temp, tempad, cvPoint(10, 10), cvScalar(0,0,0,0), cvScalar(1,1,1,1));
```

for hiding the overlay image like 
[image: image1]

```
OverlayImage(temp, tempad, cvPoint(10, 10), cvScalar(1,1,1,1), cvScalar(0,0,0,0));
```

for displaying 
[image: image2]

The way I used those functions is :

```
if (frame_number < 400)
    OverlayImage(temp, tempad, cvPoint(10, 10), cvScalar(1,1,1,1), cvScalar(0,0,0,0));
else 
    OverlayImage(temp, tempad, cvPoint(10, 10), cvScalar(0,0,0,0), cvScalar(1,1,1,1));
```

But the first image has some distorted area, I wish to make that image disappear after 400 frames of the video. How can I make that area clear ?

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by *for hiding the overlay image*? Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to hide the overlay image, simply don't call `OverlayImage()` to draw it.

Comment: By hiding I mean that I want to remove the image from there! But I have to begin with showing the image and after 400 frames the image should be removed and for that I have that `if() else`

Comment: Just make a copy of the image without the overlay, and then when you don't want to display the overlayed image then show the copy.

Comment: If this answers your question I'll be happy to write an official answer.

Comment: @karlphilip Yes ... this did help me. Kindly, write this as the official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can **make a copy of the image without the overlay**, and then when you don't want to display the overlayed image you can **show the copy** instead.